# How to create a new variable from an existing variable with values above 4

Tags: r

Hello I'm wanting to create a new variable from an existing variable in my data that only includes values above 4, whilst also retaining its association with the other variables and the participant ID, so that I may use it for analysis. I have tried the following code but i had trouble with it:

```
mutate(df, Highvar = ifelse(var > 4, (I didn't know what to enter here)
```

I would very much appreciate your help, thanks so much

Comment: please share a reproducible sample of your data set by `dput(head(data))` so that we can have a clearer idea of the actual data set.

Comment: `mutate(df, Highvar = ifelse(var > 4, var, NA)) `

Comment: Thank you @AnilGoyal the code worked perfectly!